# “Linker command” error when AdMob is present via React Native Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-firebase

XCode “`Archive`” results in an error when AdMob pod is installed via React Native Firebase.

I installed React Native 60 by the below command.

```
react-native init MyProjectName
```

It came with a Podfile by default, by the way. 
 
I followed the installation instruction here to add `Firebase Core` and then `Firebase AdMob` in that order.

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/getting-started
 
 
It still compiles build to run on iPhone simulator even with AdMob installed. It only returns the error when I try to “`Archive`” it for release. 
When only Firebase core is present, the Xcode can “Archive” properly. The problem seems to be with AdMob specific.

[image: Linker command error on Xcode 10]

Here is the error message: 
Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: could not reparse object file in bitcode bundle: 'Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '1001.0.46.4.0_0' Reader: '1000.11.45.5_0')', using libLTO version 'LLVM version 10.0.0, (clang-1000.11.45.5)' for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Environment:

```
OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
XCode: Version 10.1
```

dependencies list in package.json:

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.4",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.5.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
"react-navigation": "^3.11.1"
```

Any pointer would be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was solved once I updated XCode from 10.1 to 10.3...

It no longer throws an error. And it compiles the release build as expected.